# Slow aggregate query with join on same table

Tags: mysql, sql, expressionengine

I have a query to show customers and the total dollar value of all their orders. The query takes about 100 seconds to execute.

I'm querying on an ExpressionEngine CMS database. ExpressionEngine uses one table `exp_channel_data`, for all content. Therefore, I have to join on that table for both customer and order data. I have about 14,000 customers, 30,000 orders and 160,000 total records in that table.

Can I change this query to speed it up?

```
SELECT link.author_id          AS customer_id, 
       customers.field_id_122  AS company, 
       Sum(orders.field_id_22) AS total_orders 
FROM   exp_channel_data customers 
       JOIN exp_channel_titles link 
         ON link.author_id = customers.field_id_117 
            AND customers.channel_id = 7 
       JOIN exp_channel_data orders 
         ON orders.entry_id = link.entry_id 
            AND orders.channel_id = 3 
GROUP  BY customer_id
```

Thanks, and please let me know if I should include other information.

**UPDATE SOLUTION**

My apologies. I noticed that `entry_id` for the `exp_channel_data` table customers corresponds to `author_id` for the `exp_channel_titles` table. So I don't have to use `field_id_117` in the join. `field_id_117` duplicates `entry_id`, but in a TEXT field. JOINING on that text field slowed things down. The query is now **3 seconds**

However, the inner join solution posted by @DRapp is **1.5 seconds**. Here is his sql with a minor edit:

```
SELECT
  PQ.author_id CustomerID,
  c.field_id_122 CompanyName,
  PQ.totalOrders
FROM
  ( SELECT
       t.author_id
          SUM( o.field_id_22 ) as totalOrders
       FROM
          exp_channel_data o
       JOIN 
          exp_channel_titles t ON t.author_id = o.entry_id AND o.channel_id = 3
       GROUP BY
          t.author_id ) PQ
  JOIN 
     exp_channel_data c ON PQ.author_id = c.entry_id AND c.channel_id = 7
  ORDER BY CustomerID
```

Comment: Can you post the results of an EXPLAIN query?  I'm guessing that your tables are not indexed well for this operation.  All of the columns that you join on should probably be indexed.  As a first guess I'd look at indexing exp_channel_data.field_id_117.

Comment: You are correct, `exp_channel_data.field_id_117` is not indexed. It's actually a TEXT field as are all fields except for key fields in that table. So I changed it to varchar so I could add an index, and that helped a lot. Turns out I didn't need `field_id_117` though as in my update. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the same table, then the same columns across the board for all alias instances.
I would ensure an index on (channel_id, entry_id, field_id_117 ) if possible.  Another index on (author_id) for the prequery of order totals

Then, start first with what will become an inner query doing nothing but a per customer sum of order amounts..  Since the join is the "author_id" as the customer ID, just query/sum that first.  Not completely understanding the (what I would consider) poor design of the structure, knowing what the "Channel_ID" really indicates, you don't want to duplicate summation values because of these other things in the mix.

```
select
      o.author_id,
      sum( o.field_id_22 ) as totalOrders
   FROM
      exp_channel_data customers o
   where
      o.channel_id = 3
   group by
      o.author_id
```

If that is correct on the per customer (via author_id column), then that can be wrapped as follows

```
select
      PQ.author_id CustomerID,
      c.field_id_122 CompanyName,
      PQ.totalOrders
   from
      ( select
              o.author_id,
              sum( o.field_id_22 ) as totalOrders
           FROM
              exp_channel_data customers o
           where
              o.channel_id = 3
           group by
              o.author_id ) PQ
      JOIN exp_channel_data c
         on PQ.author_id = c.field_id_117 
        AND c.channel_id = 7
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I realized later that I didn't have to use `field_id_117` in the join which was the main problem, but your query was still twice as fast.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the results of an `EXPLAIN` query?

I'm guessing that your tables are not indexed well for this operation. All of the columns that you join on should probably be indexed. As a first guess I'd look at indexing `exp_channel_data.field_id_117`

Comment: You are right, `exp_channel_data.field_id_117` was the devil. It was a TEXT field so it couldn't even be indexed. Fortunately, I found out later that I didn't have to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Possibly you have error in joins. also check whether joins on columns are correct in your databases. Cross join may takes time to fetch large data, by mistake if your joins are not proper on columns.

```
select 
link.author_id as customer_id, 
customers.field_id_122 as company, 
sum(orders.field_id_22) as total_or_orders

from exp_channel_data customers     
join exp_channel_titles link on (link.author_id = customers.field_id_117 and
link.author_id = customer.channel_id = 7)
join exp_channel_data orders on (orders.entry_id = link.entry_id and orders.entry_id = orders.channel_id = 3)
group by customer_id
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried with the join conditions in your query, but unfortunately no results returned.

Comment: Possibly your joins or the column names you specified are wrong. try simply without using aliases. Should also try to use as less as possible tables for joins.